# Get rid of multiple bamboo build plans

Tags: git, bamboo

I have Atlassian Bamboo and multiple (around 50) git repositories. All repositories have the same plan. Should I have 50 plans for building 50 repos? Of course every plan is a clone.

I have to come up with a plan to build and deploy. Is there any way to maintain fewer plans and work on multiple repos?

Note: Individual repo will be built separately.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a single plan then you will have to trigger that plan via web hooks/git hooks from each of your repositories for every commit they receive. This means that everytime any of the repositories notice a change being pushed, they notify bamboo to run build plan and also set a variable in bamboo that stores which git repository was changed

Here is the rest documentation where you can find how to trigger a bamboo plan remotely. https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/4.0/#idp263696

You will have to define plan variable(s) to store repository name/URL and other information that is repository specific like a branch name in the git repository from where the bamboo build is remotely triggered. Set this variable using the bamboo rest API. Once set, you can have a shell script task in Bamboo to run `git clone <${bamboo.git_url_variable}>` which will clone the repository. You can have the rest of the bamboo build tasks after this step to work on this repository.

Don't use bamboo linked repositories and disable any bamboo default triggers for implementing above.

I will suggest there is no harm in using separate plans for all the repositories if they are producing distinct artefacts, in-fact you should use separate plans for different sourcecode. Managing multiple plans is very simple if you manage them using plan templates which mean converting them as source code. See more here https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-907

Plan templates help you to manage changes to all your plans in one shot

Comment: How can i trigger bamboo build remotely ?? using remote trigger ?

Comment: You can use bamboo rest API. Do curl with shell or if you have python or any other language, it is even better. https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo/REST/5.8.0/#d2e653 is the exact rest call for this

Comment: want to know how plan templates are created? Does it need any plugin ?
or it is an built feature.
Goal is maintain one central plan for all 50 repos to build,...,etc.
Im creating 50 individual plans cloned from one plan. but problem raises when i want to change. if one plan changed all have to change. Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: Your answers been more precise.Could not get more from google. please mail me - sandeeplinux.deb@gmail.com. need help
thank you.

Comment: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.valens.bamboo-templatedplans-plugin
Check this out.